# regex two words search in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I  want to in below sample text using regex find:

- The lines having keyword "Loves" and ends with "
- Append " Very Much" only to those lines which satisfy the above.

I have tried searching for:

```
Loves*."$
```

And replace with `/1 Very Much` but no luck, pointers are appreciated.

I am using Notepad++ for this.

```
"Sample Text"
--------------------

    DOLLY Loves DOLLS" Like Elephant"
    DOLLY;
    DOLLY Loves DOLLS Like Dog"
    DOLLY Loves DOLLS Like Cat" But Bats Not
    DOLLY "Loves" Her Lover Matt"
    Mr. O' Neil" King Hates Dolls
    DOLLY Loves DOLLS Like Bat"
    DOLLY;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression in Notepad++.

```
Find: \b(Loves.*")$
Replace: \1 Very Much
```

**Note:** Make sure "Regular expression" is checked and `.` matches newline is unchecked.

Comment: Appending 'Very Much' only to Line 7 but missing on Lines 1 and 3 ( Elephant and dog) not sure why that skipping..

Comment: The replace should be `$1`, not `\1`, but otherwise this looks good. Actually, it looks like either one works. Nevermind.

Comment: +1 hwnd ". matches new line" is the issue, after unchecking.regex it applied on all search pattern lines. Thank you very Much!

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but should work.  Make sure case-insensitive matching is on. Search:

```
(Loves.*")$
```

Replace

```
$1 Very Much
```

Also, make sure you're doing a global replace (Replace All). Otherwise, it will only match the first instance after the cursor. See this [**Regex101 demo**](http://regex101.com/r/oY6uP0/1)

Comment: Thanks for the quick Answer.But its applying  change for only 1 line  `"DOLLY Loves DOLLS Like Bat"` Other lines missing like Elephant, Dog etc

Comment: Make sure you're doing a global replace (Replace All). Otherwise, it will only match the first instance after the cursor. See this demo: https://regex101.com/r/oY6uP0/1